# experienced issue with expressjs/nodejs after updating connect

Tags: express, node.js-connect

I am currently using the following versions of node & express

```
(ubuntu):
node: 0.6.12
express: 2.5.8
```

I believe I am using `connect v2.0.3`.

The error spawns from the `http/https.js` file inside the `express/lib/http.js` file (I am referencing http/https in my main app js file):

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
express/lib/http.js:50:35
```

Any thoughts would be welcome on how to resolve the issue - do I need to change the connect version being used or some other solution that can be used to resolve the issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the [readme file](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect) says that it's compatible with node 0.6x, I've generally had plenty of issues with connect and have solved them by installing an older version of it. Try the latest of v1 - `npm install connect@1.8.6`

Comment: I switched back to connect v.1.7+ since the express version I am using mentions that.  Issue resolved (I also made sure that I did not have multiple connect modules while trying to resolve the issue).  Thanks Straseus.